# Flux store dependency with async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm having problems understanding what is the best way to do this using the Flux pattern. Say for example that I have a `userStore` and I listen to it. Once it changed, I need get the `user.name` and access `colors[user.name]` - but the `colors` object comes from another `colorsStore` store I have. Here's the essence of it:

```
var self = {};
userStore.addListener(function(user) {
  // dependency with the colors store
  var color = self.colors[user.name]
})
colorsStore.addListener(function(colors) {
  self.colors = colors;
})

actions.getUser() // modifies userStore
actions.getColors() // modifies colorsStore
```

The problem is that the two actions are async (they get the data from an AJAX call for instance). With this in mind, the `userStore` might change before the `self.colors` variable is populated from the other store.

How is this handled using the Flux pattern? Does the `Dispatcher` help with this somewhat? Sorry but I'm new to the Flux pattern. Intuitively I would simply call the async actions in the appropriate order such as:

```
actions.getColors() // need to populate self.colors before running getUser()
  .then(actions.getUser())
```

But was wondering if there was a more Flux-way of doing this.

Comment: why not have a general onChange function that you call from both of those listeners? check if color is already set.. if not when user comes in then set user.. when colors comes in you have colors and user so you can access it properly

Comment: Have you looked into using promises? This sounds like a classic use case for `promise.all`

Comment: Do colorsStore.colors change? Are other components using colorsStore.colors.

Comment: @JanakaStevens yes and yes.

Comment: Is it just the initial ajax call for the two stores thats connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is fine from flux perspective.
Your component needs to be able to handle different possible (stores) states generated by your actions, which could possibly include:

- user store has old/no data, colors store already has newest data
- user store has newest user data, colors store still has old data

If you want any of these states to be visible to the user in some way (eg show loading indicator, show old color/ default color while waiting for newest color), then the react-flux way is to deal with these states inside your component.

If you do not want to show anything about these states to user, you have two options:

- inside your component, fire the `actions.getUser()` from inside the colorStore listener function (quick and dirty solution)
- change the setup to prevent the unwanted store state to trigger component update

For the second solution, you could typically do:

- have you component fire both actions
- both listeners trigger the same function `getStateFromStores()`
- this function fetches state from both stores, and only does component update (`setState()`) if user and colors match

That way, your async calls can come back in any order.

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you give feedback so I could improve my answer?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use [waitFor](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html) for this case. Also there's the discussion about ["waitFor vs combining stores into one"](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/d77ca812015c0356654f), so a combined store can solve your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks, `waitFor` does make sense, however the above code exists at the UI-level (where I'm listening for store changes and don't have access to the dispatcher). Also I don't want my stores to waitFor other stores because they're only tied together in this specific view - that's why I put the logic in the stores listeners. Any idea? Not sure I understand the 'combining store' concept. How would that work?

Comment: The `waitFor` structure is (AFAIK) for making one store wait for another store following 1 dispatch. If I understand correctly, your case is about processing 2 dispatches (2 ajax responses) in a particular order. In that case, `waitFor` would not help, or would at least need a special implementation that requires more clarification.

Comment: @wintvelt it's not right about `waitFor`. If you have a user profile page and you need to load user information and e.g. notifications, you can create one action "loadUserProfile" and 2 stores (e.g. "profile" and "notification") will handle the action. Anyway, it definitely depends on your purpose and in one case it can work and in another - don't.

Comment: waitFor is good for 1 dispatch going to 2 stores (as in your example, with 1 message containing both profile and notification). This case is different: there are 2 Ajax calls + responses, so 2 dispatches, and each is for a different store. WaitFor does not address that, as far as I know.